# AttributeError at /social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/ 'Request' object has no attribute 'login'

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0, django-socialauth

[image]

I had written a REST API service on python using django rest framework to which I wanted to attach authentication from authorizations using OAuth2 (Google). I used to social django lib, however when I was starting my service locally and putting my credentials in google form to auth I keep getting this error (look at image)...

The point where the error began `auth = request.login` in `/messenger/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py, line 479, in prepare_request`.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the entire virtual environment, as well as all the places in the `settings.py` file that were responsible for auth. It helped me.
Also you can check URLs and Redirect URLs on console.cloud.google.com where you have registered your web app.